# Sed Statement not working Linux Raspbian

Tags: linux, sed, raspbian

when issuing this command:

```
sed -i 's/"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM"/"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I $TERM"/g' /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```

or

```
sed -i s/"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM"/"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I $TERM"/g /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```

or

```
sed -i s/'ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM'/'ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I $TERM'/g /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```

I get the following error:

```
sed -i 's/"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM"/"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I $TERM"/g' /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown option to `s'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "s#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I $TERM#g"  /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```

The above line should go, give it a try!

Your problem:

- should be in this format: `"s/foo$var1/bar$var2/g"`
- if pattern/replacement has slash too, you have to either escape the `s/../../` slash or use other separator.

Answer (score 1):

Change the de-limiter string from `/` to something else like `;` when trying to replace character strings involving `/` in the substitution part.

```
sed -i.bak 's;"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM";"ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I $TERM";g' /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```